# How does Breath Weapon interact with stealth?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Say a hidden Dragonfire Adept (DfA) (Dragon Magic, p.24) uses their Breath Weapon on someone.

- Can the victim scream in pain? Even if the attack does enough damage to drop them?
- What can they tell about whence the attack originated?
- How  loud is the Breath  Weapon itself (relative to a victim and relative to bystanders)?

Answer (score 1):

- Undefined. The rules don't touch talking much, for good reason, I'd argue. Closest I can imagine is the fact that talking is a free action, but since the rules don't actually say you can't act when dead, that's still not a complete argument.
- Yes, they can tell from where the attack originated, since the dragon breath is a complete area that stretches back to the user, and each of the elements is visible. This would give them a pretty tight picture about what square you were in, probably should give them a free Spot check, and also arguably lights up the area temporarily, preventing you from benefiting from darkness for that check. Up to the DM and getting away from RAW there though.
- Undefined and left purely up to the DM.

Comment: With dragons anyway (and, probably, other breath weapon using creatures, although this is in the dragon rules), the second point gets a little weird: ["A blast from a breath weapon always starts at any intersection adjacent to the dragon and extends in a direction of the dragon’s choice"](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm) (*MM* 69). Thus--after resolving arguments about adjacency--an invisible dragon *could* confuse his breath weapon victims as to his space.